# fastest way to get value frequency stored in dictionary format in groupby pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, frequency

In order to calculate frequency of each value by id, we can do something using value_counts and groupby.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,1,1,2,2,2], "col":['a','a','b','a','b','b']})
>>> df
   id col
0   1   a
1   1   a
2   1   b
3   2   a
4   2   b
5   2   b
>>> df.groupby('id')['col'].value_counts()
id  col
1   a      2
    b      1
2   b      2
    a      1
```

But I would like to get results stored in dictionary format, not Series. So how am I able to achieve that and also the speed is fast if we have a large dataset?
The ideal format is:

```
id
1    {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
2    {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unstack the groupby result to get a dict-of-dicts:

```
df.groupby('id')['col'].value_counts().unstack().to_dict(orient='index')
# {1: {'a': 2, 'b': 1}, 2: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

If you want a Series of dicts, use `agg` instead of `to_dict`:

```
df.groupby('id')['col'].value_counts().unstack().agg(pd.Series.to_dict)

col
a    {1: 2, 2: 1}
b    {1: 1, 2: 2}
dtype: object
```

I don't recommend storing data in this format, objects are generally more troublesome to work with.

---

If unstacking generates NaNs, try an alternative with `GroupBy.agg`:

```
df.groupby('id')['col'].agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict())

id
1    {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
2    {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But unstacking the series will generate nan value if an ID doesn't have certain keys. How can we remove the keys if the value is nan from the result?

Comment: @M.Cong hmm that will be tough, because you will need apply with a lambda, which will impose a slowdown.

Comment: @M.Cong Here is an alternative that doesn't unstack so nans are not generated. Perhaps this would be useful for you?

Answer (score 2):

We can do `pd.crosstab`

```
pd.Series(pd.crosstab(df.id,df.col).to_dict('i'))
1    {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
2    {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dtype: object
```